# Canvas context.measureText not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to add background to a sentence and draw it on canvas.

On click on animate button, the text-background (red) drawn improperly on first word. When consoled measuretext() on that word, the value is way lesser.

Here is the function which animates and add text background.

```
const fillMixedText = (canv, ctx, args, x, y) => {
  let defaultFillStyle = "black";
  let defaultFont = "600 54px Arial";
  ctx.save();
  let i = 0;
  args.forEach(({ text, fillStyle, font }) => {


    // console.log("x",x);
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.textBaseline = "top";

    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
      console.log(x,text,ctx.measureText(text).width)
      ctx.fillRect(x, y, ctx.measureText(text).width , 70);

    // console.log(text, ctx.measureText(text).width);
    ctx.fillStyle = fillStyle || defaultFillStyle;

    ctx.font = defaultFont;
    ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
    x += ctx.measureText(text).width;
    i++;
  });
  ctx.restore();
};
```

This is the  **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anish_jana/8f62mg4z/18/)**

I want the whole sentence to get a background.

Comment: What is the question ? Do you want the sentence with red background ?

Comment: yes, I want the sentence to have a red background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`measureText` will use the currently set `font` property, and is also relative to the current context's transform (well, its scale at least).

So you must use it with the actual settings you'll be drawing your text with to get a correct measure:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas-1");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var args = [
  {text: "constantinople "},
  {text: "is "},
  {text: "a "},
  {text: "city. "}
];


document.getElementById('click').onclick = function() {
  var startTime = new Date().getTime();
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (new Date().getTime() - startTime > 2000) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.width);

    animateText();
  }, 33);

}

var interval;
let distance = 0;
let speed = 15;

function animateText() {
  // interval = setInterval(function() {
  distance = distance + speed;
  textAnimation(
    ctx,
    canvas,
    args, -200,
    canvas.height / 2,
    distance
  ); // console.log(thiscanvas.width/16)
}

textAnimation = (ctx, canv, args, x, y, distance) => {
  if (distance >= 280) {
    distance = 0;
    // clearInterval(interval);
    x = canv.width / 16;
  }

  fillMixedText(canv, ctx, args, x + distance, y);
};

const fillMixedText = (canv, ctx, args, x, y) => {
  let defaultFillStyle = "black";
  let defaultFont = "600 54px Arial";
  ctx.save();
  let i = 0;
  args.forEach(({ text, fillStyle, font }) => {

    // console.log("x",x);
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.textBaseline = "top";

    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    // set the font first
    ctx.font = defaultFont;
    // now it's correct
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, ctx.measureText(text).width, 70);

    ctx.fillStyle = fillStyle || defaultFillStyle;
    ctx.fillText(text, x, y);

    x += ctx.measureText(text).width;
    i++;
  });
  ctx.restore();
};
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas-1" width="1280px" height="720px"></canvas>
<button id="click">animate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Anish's question, the accepted answer is correct. However, since the title can refer to several different types of problems, it may attract people that are experiencing the problem I saw.

I was trying to center text based on the text's width. Unfortunately, the measureText(text).width was returning the "incorrect" value.

From [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextMetrics#measuring_text_width):

> When measuring the x-direction of a piece of text, the sum of actualBoundingBoxLeft and actualBoundingBoxRight can be wider than the width of the inline box (width), due to slanted/italic fonts where characters overhang their advance width.

> It can therefore be useful to use the sum of actualBoundingBoxLeft and actualBoundingBoxRight as a more accurate way to get the absolute text width:

Since the font I was using was "slanted", the width property wasn't giving me what I was looking for.

Instead, I used:

```
const text = 'Hello World';
context.font = "28px Ambar Pearl Personal Use"
const metrics = context.measureText(text);
const textWidth = metrics.actualBoundingBoxRight + metrics.actualBoundingBoxLeft;
```